# Lottery scheduler in xv6 - random number generator causing kernel to fail

Tags: c, xv6

I am trying to implement lottery scheduling in xv6, and I seem to face an error. I need help with the debugging directions. Here is my code:

In proc.c

I modified function void scheduler and added a new function for random number generation:

```
unsigned long next=1;
int randomGen(int rand_max){
   next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
   int rand=((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
   //above are the default implemenation of random generator with random max value 32768
   //need to map it to the 
   int result =rand % rand_max+1;
   return result;
}
```

When I trying booting the emulator and kernel using qemu, after I press continue, I get this error:

panic: init exiting
 80104478 80106210 80105461 80106729 8010651d 0 0 0 0 0

It seems to be coming from log.c

Comment: Are you sure nothing calls `randomGen(0)`? It would cause divide by zero error.

Comment: Nope i use like this - int Lottery = randomgen(totalTicket);

Comment: and totalTicket never equals 0?